# Check if at least one child has a specific value with xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XML:

```
<LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>Al</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W-G</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>Al</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W-R</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>F</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>R</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>F</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>G</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
    <LIGHT_INFORMATION>
        <LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>F</LIGHT_CHARACTERISTICS>
        <LIGHT_COLOUR>W</LIGHT_COLOUR>
    </LIGHT_INFORMATION>
</LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST>
```

I woul insert a control:

if at least one element of LIGHT_COLOUR into this LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST contain '-'

I tried whit this, but is completely wrong:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains(.,'-'))">
        <!-- do A -->  
    </xsl:when>    
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- do B -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

This is actually my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_INFORMATION">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_COLOUR">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains(.,'-'))"> <!-- This is the test Required -->
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::LIGHT_RANGE >= 15">
                        <span style="font-family:Univers Condensed; font-weight:bold;">
                            <xsl:if test="not(preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF])">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test=". != preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </span> 
                    </xsl:when> 
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:if test="not(preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF])">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test=". != preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            ciao <!-- I would insert this control here if LIGHT_COLOUR contain '-' -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Now the output is:

ciao ciao R G W

I would, if only one element in this node of LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST contains into LIGHT_COLOUR  '-' write 'Ciao'

Comment: I suggest you clarify your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26238335/xml-element-distinct-using-xslt-1-0) instead of starting another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thi is the solution:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_INFORMATION">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains(parent::LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST//LIGHT_COLOUR, '-'))"> <!-- This is the solution -->
            <xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_COLOUR">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::LIGHT_RANGE >= 15">
                        <span style="font-family:Univers Condensed; font-weight:bold;">
                            <xsl:if test="not(preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF])">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test=". != preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </span> 
                    </xsl:when> 
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:if test="not(preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF])">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test=". != preceding::LIGHT_COLOUR[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID = $EF]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>       
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        Ciao
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Insert the control at the head and using PARENT.

Answer (score -1):

following-sibling would only find a LIGHT_COLOR if it were on the same level (ie the current node was a LIGHT_CHARACTERISTIC node and even then it would only ever find one.

To look at all of them, you need to specify a path that includes them all, either globally or relative to the current node. In this case:

```
/LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_COLOUR
```

This path will select all LIGHT_COLOR nodes. Now we want to filter out each node if it does not contain a "-":

```
/LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_COLOUR[contains(., "-")]
```

We aren't actually interested in any of the individual nodes, we just want to know how many there are so:

```
count (/LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_COLOUR[contains(., "-")])
```

Therefore, your check would be:

```
<xsl:when test='count (/LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST/LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_COLOUR[contains(., "-")])'>
```

*** Edit: Revised answer to revised question ***
If you want one control, then you only want to do it once so move it outside of the loop:

```
<!-- Do this where we can see all of the LIGHT_COLOR tags -->
<xsl:if test="contains(LIGHT_INFORMATION/LIGHT_COLOR, '-')">
Ciao
</xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_INFORMATION">
    <!-- as per your existing code. Remove the "otherwise" clause that is creating multiple controls. -->
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `count()` - a `test` whose value is a node set is false if the set is empty and true if it isn't.

Comment: True, but I figured it would be easier for a beginner to understand with the extra step.

Comment: If into this group of LIGHT_INFORMATION_LIST, there are only one LIGHT_COLOUR with '-' do X or give false.